# List remove duplicates

Tags: python-3.x, list, duplicates, uppercase

In the `for` cycle there is a function to remove all duplicates, but it doesn't. Also the `.upper` sometimes doesn't work. Please help.

```
from collections import OrderedDict
def ask():
  global x
  x = str(input("Enter your logical operation:"))
  x = x.split( )
  x = [x.upper() for x in x]
  return x

ask()

for i in range(0,len(x)):
  and_index = x.index("AND",i)
  n = list(OrderedDict.fromkeys(str(and_index)))
  print(n)

print(n)
```

Comment: How about using `set` ?

Comment: How? Please elaborate

Comment: use set to remove duplicates from list

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do you remove duplicates from a list whilst preserving order?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/480214/how-do-you-remove-duplicates-from-a-list-whilst-preserving-order)

Comment: Thanks but I fail to put it into my code and make it work

Comment: mylist = ["a", "b", "c", "a", "b"]

newlist = list(set(mylist))

print(newlist)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you're not even saving output of your `ask()` function, but instead serving it globally, that's not a good practice.

```
def ask():
  x = input("Enter your logical operation:")
  return list(map(str.upper, x.split()))

user_input = ask()
```

Then to simply remove duplicates you could convert your `list` to [`set`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#sets), doing so will loose order of our list but will quickly and easly remove duplicates

```
user_input = list(set(user_input))
```

In case you want to keep order of operations entered by user you could use [OrderedDict](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict)

```
from collections import OrderedDict
user_input = list(OrderedDict.fromkeys(user_input))
```

Answer (score 1):

Example to remove duplicate from list

```
mylist = ["a", "b", "c", "a", "b"]
newlist = list(set(mylist))
print(newlist)
```

output : ["a", "b", "c"]